# Java Script Function Not working in second loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

When the page load the loop start and the java script function also work in the first row of loop but in the second loop it not working the multiplication does not work you can see in the pic ( unit rate * quantity = total price)

### [image]

```
                foreach($db->getRecordSet($sqlTrRecord) as $row){$counter += 1; ?>
                 <tr id="temTr" class="banktblhd">
                <td width="5"> <?php echo($counter); ?> </td>


          <td class="w10"> <input type="text" name="item_code" id="item_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($row['item_code']); ?>" readonly  /></td>
          <td class="w20"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo($row['item_name']); ?>" readonly /> </td>
          <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo($row['description']); ?>" readonly /></td>
          <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="availableQty" id="availableQty" value="<?php echo($row['quantity']); ?>" readonly  /></td>
          <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit_rate" id="unit_rate" onKeyUp="total()" value="<?php echo($row['unit_rate']); ?>" readonly /></td>
          <td class="w10">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" onKeyUp="total()" autocomplete="off" /> </td>

          <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_price" id="total_price" value="" />
          </td>
</tr>
--------------------------

function total(){
    var unitRate= document.getElementById("unit_rate");
    var qty = document.getElementById("quantity");

    var total = unitRate.value * qty.value;

    document.getElementById("total_price").value = total;
}
```

Comment: You cannot give the same ID to more than one element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) When posting a question purely about client-side technologies (JavaScript operating on the DOM, for instance), post what the **browser** sees, not the server-side code that generates what the browser sees. More: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot give the same ID to more than one element. It's invalid HTML. If you do, `getElementById` will typically return the *first* (but it could do anything, including returning none, since again it's invalid).

In your case, the minimal changes necessary to make this work are:

1. Remove all those `id`s in the rows, you don't need them. Keep the `name`s on the `input`s.
2. Pass `this` into `total` everywhere you call it so it knows what element the `keyup` occurred on, e.g.:

   ```
   <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity" onKeyUp="total(this)" autocomplete="off" />
   <!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^       -->
   ```
3. Update `total` to receive that as a parameter, and to find the various inputs in the same row by traversing the DOM:

   ```
   function total(element) {
       var row = element.closest("tr");
       var unitRate = row.querySelector("input[name=unit_rate]");
       var qty = row.querySelector("input[name=quantity]");

       // (Note you're relying on implicit coercion from string to number here)
       var total = unitRate.value * qty.value;

       row.querySelector("input[name=total_price]").value = total;
   }
   ```

   That works by finding the row containing the element the event occurred on, and then using [`Element#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) with CSS selectors to find the various `input`s *within* that row.

Note that that uses [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which is fairly new. To avoid using it, you could replace

```
var row = element.closest("tr");
```

with

```
var row = element;
while (row && row.tagName !== "TR") {
    row = row.parentNode;
}
```

---

A couple of side notes:

- `keyup` isn't a reliable event to use to update the total field, because it doesn't fire if the user updates the field via the mouse (for instance, right-clicking and choosing paste from the context menu). I'd suggest using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event.
- Using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers is not best practice, not least because they can only call global functions (or methods on the element, containing form if any, etc.). Instead, you could use an event handler registered on the table and use the `target` of the event object to know which element the event targeted (and thus what row to work in). That's possible because `input` and [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) both bubble.

Comment: Now it work for me. but when the page refresh the value in the total and the quantity are gone and then you should enter the quantity to get the total value.

Comment: @SikandarKhan: That would be an unrelated problem: If you want them filled in, you need to fill in a default quantity, and do the initial total for all rows.